# varchar to int error difficult to understand

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hello I am trying to do this

```
declare @idlist varchar(100)
set @idlist = '0,1,2,3,10'


select * from CUSTOMERS where ID_CUSTOMER in (@idlist)
```

and i got

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0,1,2,3,10' to
>   data type int.

Why?

i would like to make it work, i must use @IdList as defined above. THis is a constraint (in my real case @IdList is a parameter i pass from an applicatino, anyway with this simple query i can reproduce the issue.

I found a solution using

```
execute ( 'select * from CUSTOMERS WHERE ID_CUSTOMER IN ('+@idlist+')')
```

but this forces me using `EXECUTE`, while the conversion error i got suggests me to search for another solution.

Comment: A *single* string that happens to contain sequences of digits and commas is not at *all* the same thing as multiple separate numbers provided as parameters to an `IN()` clause. This is as true in SQL as it would be in practically any language you'll have worked with. Best approach is to use a data type that natively supports storing multiple values (such as XML or table variables), but if you insist on using strings, search for "SQL Server split string" for plenty of results.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what you write does not surpirse me. I agree with you. The reason that moved me to ask is that in past i remember i did something like this, so i thought there was a hiden tsql feature i was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Try these 2 scripts:

store list as a table variable

```
declare @idlist table(id int)
insert @idlist values(0),(1),(2),(3),(10)

select * from CUSTOMERS where ID_CUSTOMER in (select id from @idlist)
```

Convert list as a logical table

```
declare @idlist varchar(100)
set @idlist = '0,1,2,3,10'

select * from CUSTOMERS where ID_CUSTOMER in (
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'INT')
FROM (
    SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
        REPLACE(@idlist, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you cast your **ID_CUSTOMER** as `varchar`. Try something like

> select * from CUSTOMERS where CAST(ID_CUSTOMER AS VARCHAR(100)) in (@idlist)

Comment: Because no single integer, coming from that column, converted to a string, will end up in a form like `0,1,2,3,10`, which is the only value being looked for by the `IN` clause.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i don't understand your comment, could you please restate it? Btw the answer provided by Naila seems to be the trick (or close to it) i was looking for.

Comment: @user193655 - it compiles, yes, and it will run, but it will never produce even a *single* row. So I'm mystified why you've accepted it as the correct answer

Comment: I think he means ('0,1,2,3,10') is not the same as ('0','1','2','3','4'). I think you're looking for the latter.

Comment: To see why, consider `select 1 where '1' in ('1,2,3')` - which produces no rows. the string `'1'` doesn't appear as any single parameter to `IN()`.

Comment: @Knightwisp - but if they're able to specify `('0','1','2','3','4')`, they could, presumably, as easily specify `(0,1,2,3,4)` and not do any mucking about with converting into strings in the first place.

Comment: `0,1,2,3,4` is a costriant i have, so it seems that EXECUTE is the only choice

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, that makes sense. I don't know what data type the column. If you're looking for integers, you wouldn't need to single quote anything

Comment: i am looking for integers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a table valued function I use to split a string to table. The original source eludes me but been using it for years.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_String_To_Table] (
        @String VARCHAR(max), /* input string */
 @Delimeter char(1),   /* delimiter */
 @TrimSpace bit )      /* kill whitespace? */
 RETURNS @Table TABLE ( [Val] VARCHAR(4000) )
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @Val    VARCHAR(4000)
 WHILE LEN(@String) > 0
  BEGIN
    SET @Val    = LEFT(@String,
         ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @String) - 1, -1),
         LEN(@String)))
    SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String,
         ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @String), 0),
         LEN(@String)) + 1, LEN(@String))
 IF @TrimSpace = 1 Set @Val = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Val))
   INSERT INTO @Table ( [Val] )
    VALUES ( @Val )
  END
 RETURN
END
```

Can use it like:

```
select * from CUSTOMERS where ID_CUSTOMER in dbo.fn_String_To_Table (@idlist, ',', 1)
```